# An API to get a given city's area size?

Tags: rest, bigdata, wikipedia, geography

I would like to find an API that would return a city's area in square feet, square miles, square meters or any area unit given only the city name.

For example, I query "san francisco" and I get something back like "231.89 sq mi or 600.6 km2".

I need this data for US and Canadian cities for now but it would be nice to have an API that covers any city in the world.

I'd rather avoid scraping wikipedia or any other website and use a proper API if at all possible.

Comment: Unfortunatly, there is no API call to get that information yet. It is being worked on, and if I had to guess, I would say it will be available within six months (but I am not on the development team, so I do not really know).

Comment: That would be awesome, considering the vast wealth of data wikipedia has!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/) to get this information. An example of [a SPARQL query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) to get this information would be:

```
select ?area where { dbr:San_Francisco dbo:areaTotal ?area }
```

Comment: That sounds interesting, but there doesn't seem to be any RESTful implementation of the API?

Comment: There is. You need to use the SPARQL endpoint http://dbpedia.org/sparql.. Here is the JSON output http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+%3Farea+where+%7B+dbpedia%3ASan_Francisco+dbpedia-owl%3AareaTotal+%3Farea+%7D&format=application%2Fsparql-results%2Bjson&timeout=30000&debug=on

Comment: Hi svick, your query not working on http://dbpedia.org/sparql . Can you update your code please. Error: Undefined namespace prefix at 'dbpedia' before 'dbpedia-owl:areaTotal'